# Symbols that syntatically correct in Javascript for template engine language design

Tags: javascript, template-engine

I need symbols that considered valid object in Javascript (to replace `<%=`, `<%!` and `%>`, so it won't considered an error by my IDE (`WebStorm`, `SublimeText3`, `Brackets.io`, `Atom.io`), so that the autocomplete would work correctly.

note: after finding the best symbol, I will modify the [template engine](https://github.com/karlseguin/gerb)'s parser source code.

[image: erb1]

`_year` would be a `string` or `number`, and `CC`, `CA`, `FS`, `FC` will be an `object`

[image: erb2]

`units_json` would be a key-value properties, something like: `rows:{1:[cell,cell,cell],2:[cell,cell,cell]},cols:[id,name,note],`

more than symbols one would be ok.

**EDIT 1**: I guess the `number` or `string` template, just need to be quoted, for example: `'<%= _year %>'` or `+'<%= _year %>'` if a number

**EDIT 2**: the `object` template, could be set as `{_:'%!` and `%'}`, for example: `{_:'%! cc_options %'}` or another workaround would be `JSON.parse('<%= cc_options %>')` but probably slower.

**EDIT 3**: the key-value properties, could be set as `/*%!` and `%*/`, for example: `/*%! units_json %*/` thanks to `damon-smith`'s answer

**EDIT 4**: it's [done](https://github.com/kokizzu/gerb)..

[image: object syntax]

[image: object property syntax]

Comment: If you make it valid code there is a chance you will confuse a placeholder with a real piece of code. PS: generating js is a strange idea at first place tbh

Comment: And it's unlikely you find one that works for every case.

Comment: yeah, I need this for generating `json5` format instead of `json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use comments, like /*[MY_TEMPLATE_VARIABLE]*/

although, @zerkms is right, you really should be thinking about other ways to do this, generating code is usually a weird and bad thing to do. Even when it's JSX and it's got a big experienced group of developers behind it. It's still bad.

Comment: "I would use comments" --- it won't work for variable assignments like on the first screen `var a = /*[MY_TEMPLATE_VARIABLE]*/;` <-- syntactically incorrect